# Does a roslaunch start roscore when needed?

Tags: roslaunch, ros-hydro, roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Ubuntu 14.04, ROS Hydro]

As per the title.
It seems to me that it does.  However I would like to have it confirmed.
(Sorry if this is silly question.)

Cheers,
Nap
(Thank you for the answer and explanations.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/217107/does-a-roslaunch-start-roscore-when-needed?/) by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2015-09-05

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it does. If there is no `roscore` already running.

As per Wiki on [roslaunch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch#roscore):

> roscore is a specialization of the
> roslaunch tool for bringing up the
> "core" ROS system.

And on [roscore](http://wiki.ros.org/roscore) itself:

> NOTE: If you use roslaunch, it will
> automatically start roscore if it
> detects that it is not already
> running.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2015-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2015-09-05**:
May be as an addition: It works, but can lead to strange behaviours if you start the core with a launch file, then some other launch files, you kill the first launchfile (and the core), start a new and nodes will not be able to connect anymore as they still rely on the old (vanished) roscore.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2015-09-05**:
True, but that is always the case, even if `roscore` was started separately. Unfortunately ROS 1.0 is designed this way. Not sure, but this behaviour might change in ROS 2.0.

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2015-09-05**:
But It's harder to kill a terminal with a roscore in it than relaunching a launch-file and forgetting which launch contained the master. I normally use a seperate tmux for the roscore so that I can forget it and not accidentially kill it together with some other terminals.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-09-05**:
ROS 2 does not have a master anymore but works completely peer-to-peer thanks to DDS.

**Comment by [Nap](https://answers.ros.org/users/9716/nap/) on 2015-09-05**:
I read the specialisation comment, but didn't see the one in the `roscore` documentation.  Cheers.